# Boot 3.0 USB on Surface Go 3 works with adapter but not with USB hub

Tags: linux, boot, usb, ssd

I'm trying to boot a permanently installed Linux from a portable SSD on my Surface Go 3.

The SSD has GRUB installed on it and basically works just line any other portable Linux. I have confirmed that it definitely boots.

I currently use it with a direct USB-C to USB-A Adapter (that supports 3.0) and it "works". It boots as it should, but the Surface Go 3 only has one single USB-C port and therefore I can't use any external devices (e.g. USB peripherals).

Now, I've tried it with a USB hub that also supports USB 3.0 but can't get the drive to boot. In theory, it should work just fine, as it boots with a direct adapter using 3.0 as well.

The Surface Go has all the latest firmware updates installed.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be and how I can try to fix it?

Comment: The fix is probably to get a better hub.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Surface Go 3, requires Secure Boot which means UEFI and it cannot be disabled due to the form factor (Microsoft has different requirements and rules for Tablets and Laptops)

Comment: As @ChanganAuto states, it may be hub-dependent. I regularly boot PC's from USB 2 and 3 devices plugged into a hub.

Comment: I have thought that the Hub might be an issue as well, but I've tried multiple Hubs by now and none worked. Weirdly enough, the Hub I just tried used to work on my old Surface Go 1 with exactly the same hard drive. I have also tried disabling secure boot to no avail.

Comment: Where and how does the boot fail ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Booting does not "fail" per se, the boot option is simply skipped without any error messages. If I try to boot the device directly, I get kicked back into the UEFI after a few seconds of splash screen. @harrymc

Comment: If this happens during POST, then the problem is with the UEFI, whose disk drivers are not very extensive. Does the adapter work correctly if you boot from the internal disk (if you can)?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking as well. I have Windows 11 installed regularly on the internal drive, which detects the hub and the drive. However, if that would be the case, why would a direct USB-C to USB-A adapter work then? The UEFI would still need xHCI support and the hub doesn't come with any unusual drivers that need to be installed. @harrymc

Comment: It's indeed weird. A weak theory is that the USB port of the Surface doesn't produce a strong enough electric power to split it up in a multi-port hub. Have you tried a self-powered hub?

Comment: That's probably not it either. If the port didn't provide enough current, then the hub would likely not work within Windows as well. The drive itself has a power LED which lights up as soon as I press the power button but does not blink to indicate data transfer when trying to boot as it usually does when copying files or booting via the adapter. It seems like it just isn't detected behind the hub for some reason. @harrymc